# Why is SQL Server losing a millisecond?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [TESTTABLE]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateField] [datetime] NULL,
    [StringField] [varchar](50),
    [IntField] [int] NULL,
    [BitField] [bit] NULL
)
```

I execute the following code:

```
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (IntField, BitField, StringField, DateField) 
   VALUES ('1', 1, 'hello', {ts '2009-04-03 15:41:27.378'});  

   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
END
```

And then

```
select * from testtable with (NOLOCK)
```

and my result shows:

```
2009-04-03 15:41:27.*377*
```

for the `DateField` column.

Any ideas why I seem to be losing a millisecond??

Comment: i noted same mistake with dates like '2008-12-31 23:59:59.999'

Comment: look at this: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-12-31 23:59:59.999')

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634122) for more details

Answer (score 100, accepted):

SQL Server only stores time to approximately 1/300th of a second. These always fall on the 0, 3 and 7 milliseconds. E.g. counting up from 0 in the smallest increment:

00:00:00.000
00:00:00.003
00:00:00.007
00:00:00.010
00:00:00.013
...

If you need that millisecond accuracy, there's no pleasant way around it. The best options I've seen are to store the value in custom number fields and rebuild it every time you fetch the value, or to store it as a string of a known format. You can then (optionally) store an 'approximate' date in the native date type for the sake of speed, but it introduces a conceptual complexity that often isn't wanted.

Comment: Be sure to read Rob Garrison's post about TIME and DATETIME2 -- these types have much higher resolution.

Comment: According to my tests on Azure SQL as of today, all of my DateTime fields have milliseconds with ones digits of 0, 3, and 6

Answer (score 45):

SQL Server 2008 has much more precision available. The datetime2 type will accurately store values like this: 2008-12-19 09:31:38.5670514 (accuracy to 100 nanoseconds).

Reference: [time and datetime2 - Exploring SQL Server 2008's New Date/Time Data Types](http://rwgarrison.com/PASS/TimeDateTime2/)

Answer (score 29):

The SQL Server [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) type only has a 1/300th of a second (~3.33̅ ms) resolution, so you are probably seeing a rounding error.

See the [MSDN Datetime SQL Server reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(SQL.80).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server is only accurate to 1/300th of a second. It will round values to the nearest 1/300th.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Makes me feel better. I just have to adjust my unit tests. :)

Comment: Close, 3/1000 resolution would be 000, 003, 006, 009... 1/300 resolution is 000, 003, 007, 010...

Answer (score 3):

DATETIME does not have infinite precision - you are probably using a value that cannot accurately be represented with the available bits.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server stores datetime values to a precision of 3 milliseconds. (I've heard about this, but can't find an official reference.)