# Linq to SQL filter DateTime field by Year/Month

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have `Statistic` table with many fields and one of them is `DateTime`. I need to find all records which are for current Year and Month. I am using query below but not sure is this optimal solution.

```
Statistics.Count(p => p.DateStamp.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year && p.DateStamp.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do more from Linq, but look at this answer how you can improve this query.. if really needed http://stackoverflow.com/a/9524353/782754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb301738.aspx):

> Counts the number of month boundaries between two non-nullable dates.
>   Corresponds to the SQL Server `DATEDIFF` function; using month to
>   specify the type of time boundary crossed.

so your query will be like this:

```
Statistics.Count(p => 
    SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth(DateTime.UtcNow, p.DateStamp) == 0
);
```