# Date functions trim off timestamp in DB2

Tags: function, date, datetime, db2

Is there a way to trim off the timestamp in a DB2 date function?

Have DB2 select statement where I'mm selecting a date form the databease and saving it to a variable. I then use that variable as a parameter for another db2 select by adding 30days to it but I don't think it agrees with the timestamp that it is adding to the end.

```
Select business_date From DB2INST1.BusDate Where key = 0
```

There is no timestamp in the database for this date but its adding '12:00:00AM' to the end

it saves this select into a variable and I use it in another select here

```
where expirdate > (DATE(@BusDate) + 30 DAYS)
```

I get this error:

> {"ERROR [428F5] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0245N  The invocation of routine \"DATE\" is ambiguous. The argument in position \"1\" does not have a best fit."} System.Exception {IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception}

Comment: This sounds like a potential application-layer issue.  What other language/frameworks are you using to access SQL?  What is the type of the host variable?  You at least seem to have the proper time, but what about 'formatting'?

Comment: The application is in Visual Studio 2008 using .NET 2.0 Framework DB2 Version 9.7

Comment: Is the first SELECT statement and the second SELECT Statement part of same stored procedure? Are you storing the resulting date in any .Net variable?

Answer (score 3):

Select business date as a varchar/string

```
 Select varchar_format(business_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

then do this to use it later, convert it to a date then use a date function to add 30days to it:

```
      (DATE(to_date(@BusDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 30 DAYS))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
where expirdate > DATE(@BusDate + 30 DAYS)
```

Comment: Can't necessarily speak for his version, but on my DB2 instance (V6R1), if `@BusDate` is anything _but_ a date/timestamp type, that fails.  The use of `DATE()` implies that the host variable isn't actually a 'date' type - and you want to make sure to convert it first _anyways_, to avoid things like ambiguities around daylight savings time.

Comment: The application is in Visual Studio 2008 using .NET 2.0 Framework DB2 Version 9.7. I know the @BusDate is a datetime stamp in the format of 12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM. When I'm testing I can manually enter a date but with no timestamp and it works but when it actually pulls the current date from the DB2 database it adds the timestamp 12:00:00 AM and makes it fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first SELECT statement and the second SELECT Statement part of same stored procedure? Are you storing the resulting date in any .Net variable? If you are storing it in a .Net DateTime variable, my suggestion is to do the `date addition` operation in .Net code itself. And then remove the time part from the variable before passing to the database.

Take a look at this too: [Datetime field overflow with IBM Data Server Client v9.7fp5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549943/datetime-field-overflow-with-ibm-data-server-client-v9-7fp5/14215249#14215249)

If both the SELECT statements were part of a stored procedure and there is no .Net DateTime variable invloved, then it is a different story.