# Convert DateTime Format with Millisecond in C#

Tags: c#

This is date time format i want "2013-06-25 18:46:54.687" to pass in to sql server.
How to convert in C#?

```
 DateTime LastUpdateTime=Convert.toDateTime(LastUpdateTime);
  //2013-06-25 18:46:54.687 with 3 index of millisecond
 sc.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = LastUpdateTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong Data Typ in SQL.

The **datetime2** can be considered as an extension of the existing datetime type that has a larger default fractional precision, and optional user-specified precision.

---

C# Format Milliseconds exactly the way you want.
In an Example:

```
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 30, 45, 125);
Console.WriteLine("Date: {0:o}", 
                  date2);           
// Displays the following output to the console:
//      Date: 2008-01-01T00:30:45.1250000
```

---

Look at [Why is SQL Server losing a millisecond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond) and [DateTime2 vs DateTime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime)

These are **great Question** with **good Answers**, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

If your database query parameter is string, use following format:

`LastUpdateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`

Otherwise, it would be better to send datetime as original object,
and let sql server do all conversions.