# Convert DateTime Time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my database table fields are saved as 2013-02-15 00:00:00.000. I want they should be 2013-02-15 23:59:59.999. So how to convert 2013-02-15 00:00:00.000 to 02-15 23:59:59.999. In other words only change minimum to maximum time.

Comment: why you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Because my business logic code testing the time

Comment: What kind of testing? I bet it's better to be done at comparasing then modifying data

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, In have live app which include a bug that need to be fixed quickly. My db have 00:00:00.000 in time field. My business check current date with current time which is causing this issue.

Comment: What datatype are you using? In SQL 2012, it can make a big difference.

Comment: @PhilipKelley, datetime

Comment: Then you'll have to use .997 -- is that bad? (More detailed answer pending, though someone will probably beat me to it)

Comment: @PhilipKelley, cusious to see your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Time TIME = '23:59:59.999'
SELECT dateColumn + @Time
FROM tableName
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8eb8/1)

Edit

Cast @time to datetime before (+)

```
DECLARE @Time TIME = '23:59:59.999'
SELECT dateColumn + CAST(@Time as DATETIME)
FROM tableName
```

Comment: I think due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond

Comment: @user960567 thanks for pointing out the thread..didn't know about precesion

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 and getting this error.
`Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: cast @time to datetime

Answer (score 2):

Easily done:

```
SELECT dateCol + '23:59:59'
```

Comment: Actually this will produce the next day date. Dunno why

Comment: I think  due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond

Answer (score 2):

The datetime datatype is not accurate to thousandths of seconds, but rather only to 333rds of a second (details in BOL, it has to do with how the data is actually stored).

Run this for an example:

```
DECLARE @Test datetime = 'Feb 15, 2013'

PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)

SET @Test = dateadd(ms, -1, @Test)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)

SET @Test = dateadd(ms, -1, @Test)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)

SET @Test = dateadd(ms, -1, @Test)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)

PRINT ''

SET @Test = dateadd(ms, -3, @Test)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)

SET @Test = dateadd(ms, -3, @Test)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)

SET @Test = dateadd(ms, -3, @Test)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @Test, 109)
```

This generates:

```
Feb 15 2013 12:00:00:000AM
Feb 15 2013 12:00:00:000AM
Feb 15 2013 12:00:00:000AM
Feb 15 2013 12:00:00:000AM

Feb 14 2013 11:59:59:997PM
Feb 14 2013 11:59:59:993PM
Feb 14 2013 11:59:59:990PM
```

So, the simplest way to update a datetime to the highest/last possible moment prior to, say, Feb 15, 2013, you need to subtract 3 milliseconds, as shown above. In a table, it would be something like:

```
UPDATE MyTable
 set MyDateTime = dateadd(ms, -3, MyDateTime)
```

Comment: SQL 2012 introduced datatypes that provide extreme precision for time, if you need them.