# Why SQL changes the exact datetime by one tick

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @dateEnd datetime
SET @dateEnd = '2014-11-30T23:59:59.999'
SELECT @dateEnd
```

Why do I get result:
`2014-12-01 00:00:00.000`

I want to use variables for the SELECT condition:

```
where [MyDate] between @dateStart and @dateEnd
```

This is another issue but related. I would like the first datapoint (dataStart) to be included and the second (dataEnd) to be excluded from the selected data range. How to do it?

Comment: Which dbms? (Certainly not ANSI/ISO SQL standard.)

Comment: Sql Server DateTimes only have [resolution of 300 quanta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/715484/314291) per second. Switch your data type if you need higher resolution.

Comment: @jarlh is this MS [sql-server] syntax.

Comment: @StuartLC Does the 300 quanta per second resolution lead to the time range described above? I'm not really sure my answer is entirely correct, having gone through the link.

Comment: @StuartLC Thanks. I've deleted my answer since I am not convinced it was correct, even if .999 rounding up to the nearest second will cause OP's results. Perhaps you'd care to add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @shree.pat18 . . .Your answer is basically correct and you should undelete it.  The documentation says that values are "rounded", so perhaps 23:59:59.998 won't "round up", but 23:59:59.999 would round up.

Comment: If you can't change data type, change your WHERE condition- WHERE MyDate >= @dateStart AND MyDate < dateEnd

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see. I should add in this explanation then, because .998 indeed left it at 23:59:59

Comment: seems we cannot user '@' + dateEnd in comment!!!

Comment: @StuartLC Yep, already did that, and updated my demo with the case for .998 as a counter-example!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is SQL Server losing a millisecond?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond)

Comment: It's almost always a better idea to start using semi-open intervals (so use `>=` and `<` rather than `between`) for querying continuous data like datetimes. It's usually easier to compute the start and end values (they tend to be simpler), and you won't end up making double-counting or non-counting errors for values close to the end values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time range for `datetime` is '00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997'. At '.999', this value gets rounded up to the nearest second, which happens to be the start of the next day, leading to the results described. For the record though, '.998' will retain the time part at '23:59:59' of the same day.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187819.aspx)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EXVO2286)

Answer (score 3):

**Precision of Sql Server's DateTime Data Type**

Just to elaborate on shree.pat's answer, Sql Server's [DATETIME data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) has a resolution of 300 'steps' or quanta per 1 second, or a resolution interval of ~3ms.

This means that accurate representation of time instants of a 1 millisecond accuracy are not possible with `DATETIME`. In the example here, `2014-11-30T23:59:59.999` will be rounded up to `2014-12-01 00:00:00.000`. Similarly, 1 millisecond prior, `2014-11-30T23:59:59.998` will be rounded to `2014-11-30T23:59:59.997`.

This query demonstrates how `DateTime` rounds the milliseconds, as compared to the actual time:

```
WITH cteMS AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o1.object_id) as MilliSeconds
    FROM sys.objects o1 CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
)
SELECT DATEADD(ms, cteMS.MilliSeconds, CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME2)) AS DT2, 
       DATEADD(ms, cteMS.MilliSeconds, CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME)) AS DT
FROM cteMS;
```

If you require accuracies of 1 millisecond or better, then you should use the [`DATETIME2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) datatype, which can represent precisions down to `100ns`.

**The problem with comparing date ranges with BETWEEN**

As per Damien's comment, your question illustrates why it is not a good idea to use `BETWEEN` to search for data which are between two Dates.

The accuracy of your query is dependent on the date type, since `where [MyDate] between @dateStart and @dateEnd` will now give different results depending on whether `@dtStart`, `@dtEnd` and the date and time column you are comparing with.

Instead, use `>=` on the lower bound (inclusive) and `<` on an excluded upper bound, like so:

```
DECLARE @dateEnd AS DateTime, or DateTime2
SET @dateEnd = '2014-11-31';
SELECT ... WHERE [MyDate] >= @dateStart AND [MyDate] < @dateEnd;
```