# MS SQL Server is dropping 1 millisecond from converted time

Tags: sql-server

The following query:

`select convert(datetime, '2016-06-20 7:22:52.728')`

gives me:

`2016-06-20 07:22:52.727`

In SQL Server v12.0.4100.1.

Whatever value I put for milliseconds, the result always has 1 less millisecond.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond

Comment: I'd like to state that the Search tool on here is not very good because I did search for an existing answer before posting.  Thanks for the answers everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how `datetime` works in sql server. If you want that millisecond, switch to `datetime2([3-7])`.

`datetime` accuracy is to 0.00333 second.

`datetime2` accuracy is to 100 nanoseconds.

[Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

Similarly, if you want to get the server time with additional accuracy, you would use `sysdatetime()` which returns `datetime2(7)` instead of `getdate()` which returns `datetime`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a bug. The resolution of datetime is such that the final digit can only be one of a few values... Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.

This is documented: [Microsoft documentation for datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)