# Cast to datetime is not working on sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am getting Arithmetic overflow error while executing following query on sql server 2016.

```
select cast(2958463.99999999 as datetime)
```

The same query works fine on sql server 2014.

[image]

Edit 1- `select cast(2958463.9999999 as datetime)` works on sql server, the only difference is that it used 7 digits after decimal point instead of 8 as originally posted.

Comment: This error is caused by a change in Microsoft SQL Server 2016's handling of datetime types.

Comment: You sure there isn't anything more in the value? I just run it on couple versions and everywhere works in the same fashion.

Comment: @YogeshSharma could you elaborate? I'm curious.

Comment: The query works fine on mine 2016 instance. The output I get is `9999-12-31 23:59:59.997`.

Comment: even 'select cast(2958463.9999999 as datetime)' with 7 digit after decimal is working on sql server 2016

Comment: which management studio are you using? You should download SQL Mangement studio 17 then it will work for you.

Comment: @mohituprim As your not clear about which instance or management studio you use, i have tried different solutions which you can see in my answer. Hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in 2016   (notice the last digit)

```
select cast(2958463.99999996 as datetime)
```

Comment: Why then it would work without this change on SQL2016s I have at hand?

Comment: This is working but i am not sure about the reason..could you please explain? thanks

Comment: @mohituprim I suspect a matter of precision.   Take a peek at this answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the newest SQL Server Management studio available.

This is both on instances with Server version 2014 (12.0.4439.1) and 2016(13.0.4435.0).

**NOTE:**

> SQL Server Management Studio 2017 only works with 7 digits on instance  2016(13.0.1601.5)

**NOTE2:**

> SQL Server Management Studio 2014 only works with 7 digits on instance
> 2016(13.0.4435.0)
>
> SQL Server Management Studio 2014 works with all digits on instance 2016(13.0.1601.5)
>
> SQL Server Management Studio 2014 works will all digits on instance 2014(12.0.4439.1)

You can download the newest version here
[SQL Server Management Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

**Tested on SQL Server instance 2016(13.0.4435.0)**
[image]

**Tested on SQL Server instance 2014(12.0.4439.1)**
[image]

**Tested on SQL Server Instance 2016(13.0.1601.5)**
[image]