# Insert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000 in datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, datetime

I have a timestamp in Excel in the format `d/m/yyy hh:mm:ss.000` and I send it to a datetime datatype in SQL Server. But when I transfer the data it has transferred correctly but without the milliseconds every data has `.000` on the end. In Excel I have the date with the correct milliseconds. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Are you using the `datetime` or `datetime2` data type?

Comment: I think the main question is... how are you transferring the data from Excel to SQL Server in the first place?

Comment: @Tony use a datetime data type.

Comment: @DarXyde I call this module to send the data to the sql server.

Comment: Convert them to the following format to send them `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000` (`Format$()`) you might also be interested in reading [Why is SQL Server losing a millisecond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond)

Comment: I have tried your format but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Sectie1Invert()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ServerName As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim UserID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim NoOfFields As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim ColCounter As Integer
Dim trigger As Boolean

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

ServerName = "NLDONL0113" ' Enter your server name here
DatabaseName = "Stroomwaarden" ' Enter your  database name here
TableName1I = "Sectie1invert" ' Enter your Table name here
 UserID = "" ' Enter your user ID here
Password = "" ' Enter your password here
NoOfFields = 1 ' Enter number of fields to update (eg. columns in your worksheet)
StartRow = 3 ' Enter row in sheet to start reading  records
EndRow = 349 ' Enter row of last record in sheet

Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 '********

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
rs.Open TableName1I, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

For RowCounter = StartRow To EndRow
   rs.AddNew
    'On Error Resume Next

     rs(0) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13)
    rs(3) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 14)

    Debug.Print RowCounter
Next RowCounter

    rs.UpdateBatch
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is not the answer to your question please edit your original question and put the code there (and then delete this answer). Don't use the answer button to add code, only use it if you want to provide an answer to the original question. You might want to take the [Tour] or read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can get Text of Cell and format before insert to db:

```
Dim strValue as String
strValue=shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text
```

format again `strValue` before insert to db `rs(0)`, if it is `datetime` type.

Comment: You can cut String or set format before get text : ex: shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).NumberFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"
rs(0)=shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text

Comment: I get type mismatch error on:
rs(0)=shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text

Comment: I can't test, You write and execute a SQL instead of UpdateBatch

Comment: Have anyone a solution? I have search but I cant find a solution.

Comment: Can you copy a datetime value of your db?

Comment: This is a value copied from the db: 2019-05-08 09:00:43.000

Comment: You try a sql ex:  Cn.Execute("Update Sectie1invert set [Col]='2019-05-08 09:00:43.123' where ID=[key]"). Is it oK?

Comment: yes this is working, do I need to use the Cn.Execute function ?

Comment: yes. you must format datetime in excel before get text.

Comment: In my excel sheet I have already set the format of the cell to Custom and :yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000

Comment: Good, You can get Text and use Execute function to update or insert.

Comment: I don't understand it for 100%. I can get the cell value in text to set .text on the end. But I don't know how I can send it with Cn,Execute function. 
Now I do it with rs.AddNew en then I send the value in the column with rs(0) and rs(3).

Comment: above you had execute ok: Cn.Execute("Update Sectie1invert set [Col]='2019-05-08 09:00:43.123' where ID=[key]")

Comment: you only set column and value to sql and execute it.

Comment: it works when I use a date like:
Cn.Execute ("Update Sectie1invert set [date]='2019-09-22 12:22:10.928' where ID=[ID]" 

But the whole column have the same date,.

Comment: If you add new, try this sql: sql="Insert Sectie1invert (Col1,Col2) values('" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text & "','" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text & "')"

Comment: I am getting a syntax error:

Cn.Execute ("Insert Sectie1invert (Col1,Col2) values('" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Text & "','" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Text &"')"

Comment: What is your sql? You must change [Col1,Col2] to column name in your db.

Comment: It is working, is it possible to send the range D2:D110 in one execute? Will that be faster to insert into the sql server?

Comment: You can try, add ";" and new line to last a sql.

Comment: When I insert this:
Cn.Execute ("Insert Sectie1invert (Sectie1invert) values('" & shtSheetToWork.Range("D2;D110").Value & "','" & shtSheetToWork.Range("E2;E110").Value & "')")


I get this error:
Method 'Range' of object'_ worksheet' failed

Comment: No.you must connect all query and execute a time: ex:   sql="Insert Sectie1invert (Col1,Col2) values('" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text & "','" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, 13).Text & "');"  & vbNewLine  &  next sql