# nhibernate, sql server Datetime compare failing

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

In nhibernate i am using following to compare date

```
Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property("SubmittedDate"), request.Data.SubmittedDateTime.Value)
```

in local environment its working. but in other environment its not returning result.

```
SubmittedDateTime? is nullable
```

do i need to mention nullable somewhere in mapping file.

Is there any change i need to do in code for this?

Comment: Do you need to compare also time? if not then try to use request.Data.SubmittedDateTime.Value.Date. Try to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872444/round-net-datetime-milliseconds-so-it-can-fit-sql-server-milliseconds

Comment: What datatype has SubmittedDateTime? What sql type is used?

Comment: SubmittedDateTime is C# nullable datetime type. and SQL type is (Datetime,null)

Comment: @StefanSteinegger SubmittedDateTime is C# nullable datetime type. and SQL type is (Datetime,null)

Answer (score 0):

Stephen,

Your problem may be (or have been) that your production server has ANSI nulls enabled [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx.  In such cases, one NULL value is not the same as another. e.g.

```
DECLARE @a INT,
        @b INT

SELECT @a = null, @b=null

IF(@a=@b)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Equal'
ELSE
    SELECT 'NOT Equal'
END
```

If you run the code below on an environment with ANSI NULLS ON, you would see 'NOT Equal'

It could also be that your dates have a time component set;

2012-09-26 22:16:00.000 <> 2012-09-26

For this, you would need to use DATEDIFF(D, Date1, Date2)=0.

NHibernate does not support this out the box, so you would need to create (or find) a custom ICriterion