# DateTime comparison with formatting in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am trying to write a simple LINQ query in which DateTime is compared to get the results. My requirement is that the DateTime has to be compared only till milliseconds and hence I have to apply formatter. The query is as follows

```
var availableValues = from value in AvailableValues
                      where DateTime.Compare(DateTime.ParseExact(value.Time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                      DateTime.ParseExact(currentTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) == 0
                      select value;
```

`AvailableValues` is huge collection and the above query is causing a perfomance hit.

It would be of great help if someone could suggest me a better way to achieve the expected result.

Comment: You could start by only parsing the currentTime once.

Comment: So a date with a difference of 1 millisecond is not considered the same date?

Comment: This question and its answer could be a valid starting point to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cache the value for the `currentTime` to avoid recalculating it for every comparison
2. As far as I understand, you only want to compare including *whole* milliseconds (no fractions, no ticks). So you can create new `DateTime` values with only whole ms like that (if your query provider allows that):

   ```
   DateTime current = new DateTime(
       currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 
       currenTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute, currentTime.Second, currentTime.Kind).
       AddMilliseconds(currentTime.Millisecond);

   var availableValues = from value in AvailableValues
       where currentTime == new DateTime(
           value.Time.Year, value.Time.Month, value.Time.Day, 
           value.Time.Hour, value.Time.Minute, value.Time.Second, value.Time.Kind).
           AddMilliseconds(value.Time.Millisecond)
       select value;
   ```

This should be a lot faster than converting your `DateTime`s to `string` and back again.

Comment: I think that he wants to compare (till) the milliseconds part not remove them

Comment: @Steve thx pointing me to my misunderstanding. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

> My requirement is that the DateTime has to be compared only till milliseconds and **hence** I have to apply formatter.

Nope, you don't have to apply a formatter. Simply create a new date with an empty millisecond component. Instead of

```
DateTime.Compare(date1, date2)
```

use

```
DateTime.Compare(DropMilliseconds(date1), DropMilliseconds(date2))
```

or, since your are only interested in [equality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) (not in the additional information that DateTime.Compare will give you):

```
DropMilliseconds(date1) == DropMilliseconds(date2)
```

with DropMilliseconds defined as follows (or any [alternative implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1004698/87698)):

```
private static DateTime DropMilliseconds(DateTime dtm)
{
    return new DateTime(dtm.Year, dtm.Month, dtm.Day, 
                        dtm.Hour, dtm.Minute, dtm.Second, 
                        dtm.Kind);
}
```

If you are worried about the method call overhead, you can [tell the compiler to aggressively inline it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/473782/87698).

Comment: In his formatter he uses "fff", so he _does want_ to compare milliseconds, but only _whole_ milliseconds, no fractions or ticks or nanoseconds.

Comment: @RenéVogt: Good point. The question can be interpreted either way (since "until" can be [inclusive or exclusive](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33340/27863)), so I'll leave my answer - it might help someone else finding this question. In any case, the principal solution is the same: [Rounding to milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2872444/87698) is even simpler than stripping them. Oh, and +1 to your answer!