# Converting a date in c# from SQL gives wrong milliseconds

Tags: c#, sql

For an unknown reason, when I read a date from the response of execute reader I obtain a date that has 000 before the actual milliseconds. So for example in the database I have 2017-04-04 12:12:12.123455 but when I display in C# I have 2017-04-04 11:12:12.000123

```
while (dr.Read())
{
lst.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr[i]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));
}
```

Comment: Lets see the code.  What is your query?  what is your DDL?  How are you displaying it?  Can't read your mind over here.

Comment: This is probably a datetime vs datetime2 problem.  Datetime isn't actually precise enough for milliseconds.  (I'm assuming SQL Server).

Comment: The query is SELECT * FROM TABLE... The code is the simplest possible. I'll edit.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @C.Helling I meant Millionth of a seconds. I want to show 6 numbers after the ",".

Comment: Yes, I see now. I am guessing the other commenters are right, there probably isn't the precision in your SQL table, but impossible to know since you haven't specified the RDBMS/column type/etc. Edit: I see your comment on the other answer, you should mention that in the original question.

Comment: datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql. See also related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872444/round-net-datetime-milliseconds-so-it-can-fit-sql-server-milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the dates are a timestamp (a number of milliseconds from a determined date in the past) to have the exact amount of milliseconds you need to have the exact time in the database server and the machine you are running the c# application.

Comment: In the db I see the exact time and if I add enough f in the format I see the good time too, but there's 3 extras 0 after the seconds like 2017-08-08 12:12:12.123456 -> 2017-08-08 12:12:12.000123456