# Saving DateTime in Datacontext sets wrong milliseconds

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datacontext

I am building a Windows Phone 8 application where I need to have milliseconds precision. The data context is as follows:
private DateTime _date;

```
    [Column]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("ItemDate");
            _date= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemDate");
        }
    }
```

In reference to this question: [Milliseconds wrong when converting from XML to SQL Server datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634122/milliseconds-wrong-when-converting-from-xml-to-sql-server-datetime) I understand that DataContext might be facing similar problems. More specifically the return value of milliseconds from the DataContext is sometimes 1 ms higher or lower – depending on the number of ticks.

So the only solution to this is to save the DateTime in an Int64 as milliseconds? Is there any other better way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to perform calculations with this data them you'll need to do something with this yourself. Internally, DateTime stores `Milliseconds` as an `Int32` so that *should* be sufficient though.

If you're just displaying this data, rather than rely on the underlying properties and behaviour of the `DateTime` class. Could you not just store/display it as a string?

Comment: Storing it as a string is clearly not an option due to operations that are being performed on the field. What i did is actually store the milliseconds since 1970 as int64 into the database and then used some converters in order to transform them to 'human readable form' whenever its needed.

Comment: Marking as answered - solution in my previous comment.