# SQL - Convert to Datetime, Millisecond Not Accurate

Tags: sql

I am seeing a very strange issue in SQL server, when converting to a datetime the milliseconds are not correct -

When I run -

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/10/2013 16:09:47.935', 103)
```

It returns -

```
2013-10-09 16:09:47.937
```

Am I missing something? Or has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634122/milliseconds-wrong-when-converting-from-xml-to-sql-server-datetime

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Have since found that DATETIME2 is more accurate. How I have been using SQL for 8 years without knowing about that I will never know... And thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this solves the problem -

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '09/10/2013 16:09:47.935', 103)
```