# MS SQL Converting a String to Datetime issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert the string to datetime, but getting an unexpected result.

```
Select Convert(DateTime, '2015-08-10 13:08:01.725', 121);
```

Result:

```
2015-08-10 13:08:01.727
```

Note that the milliseconds have changed from 725 to 727.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU2) (KB4482960) - 12.0.6214.1 (X64).

Comment: Does a `datetime2` fit your expectation better?

Comment: WHat is the expected result ?

Comment: This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634122/milliseconds-wrong-when-converting-from-xml-to-sql-server-datetime) explains a similar issue.

Comment: @AmitVerma The expected result is that the milliseconds show as 725, rather than 727. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, `datetime` is only accurate to 1/300 of a second, and .725 can't be represented by that. As a result it's rounded to the nearest 1/300, which would be .726666666666~, and then *displayed* as .727 as the display layer is accurate to 3 digits.

If you want to be accurate to 1/1000 of a second, use a more precise data type. `datetime2(3)` seems to be what you are after:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(3), '2015-08-10 13:08:01.725', 121);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `DATETIME` is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Directly from Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)